# Hadoop streaming using shell script : reducer fails with error : No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I am using a 10 node HDP cluster where I am trying to run a simple WordCount job using shell script on Bash.Below is the Commmand line arguments I am using.

```
    yarn jar /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292.jar \
    -mapper 'wc -l' \
    -reducer './reducer_wordcount.sh' \
    -file /home/pathirippilly/map_reduce_jobs/shell_scripts/reducer_wordcount.sh \
    -numReduceTasks 1 \
    -input /user/pathirippilly/cards/smalldeck.txt \
    -output /user/pathirippilly/mapreduce_jobs/output_shell
```

1. Here reducer_wordcount.sh is the reducer shell script which is available in 
   my local directory /home/pathirippilly/map_reduce_jobs/shell_scripts
2. smalldeck.txt is the input file on hadoop directory /user/pathirippilly/cards
3. /user/pathirippilly/mapreduce_jobs/output_shell is the output directory
4. The version of hadoop I am using is Hadoop 2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292
5. I am running the above map reduce job on yarn mode

reducer_wordcount.sh is having:

```
    #! /user/bin/env bash
    awk '{line_count += $1} END  { print line_count }'
```

When I run this on my cluster , I am getting below error for reducer_wordcount.sh

```
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:410)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
            at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
            at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.configure(PipeReducer.java:67)
            ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hdp01/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/pathirippilly/appcache/application_1533622723243_17238/container_e38_1533622723243_17238_01_000004/./reducer_wordcount.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
            at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
            ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

If I run the same reducer script directly as commandline commad as below, it works

```
    yarn jar /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -mapper 'wc -l' \
    -reducer "awk '{line_count += \$1} END  { print line_count }'" \
    -numReduceTasks 1 \
    -input /user/pathirippilly/cards/smalldeck.txt \
    -output /user/pathirippilly/mapreduce_jobs/output_shell
```

Expecting helping hands here, I am pretty new to hadoop streaming.
Full error stack is given below:

```
    18/09/09 10:10:02 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
    packageJobJar: [reducer_wordcount.sh] [/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292.jar] /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/hadoop_java_io_tmpdir/streamjob8506373101127930734.jar tmpDir=null
    18/09/09 10:10:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:8050
    18/09/09 10:10:03 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:10200
    18/09/09 10:10:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:8050
    18/09/09 10:10:03 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:10200
    18/09/09 10:10:05 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    18/09/09 10:10:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
    18/09/09 10:10:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1533622723243_17238
    18/09/09 10:10:08 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1533622723243_17238
    18/09/09 10:10:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://rm01.itversity.com:19288/proxy/application_1533622723243_17238/
    18/09/09 10:10:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1533622723243_17238
    18/09/09 10:10:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1533622723243_17238 running in uber mode : false
    18/09/09 10:10:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    18/09/09 10:10:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    18/09/09 10:10:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1533622723243_17238_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:410)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
            at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
            at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.configure(PipeReducer.java:67)
            ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hdp01/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/pathirippilly/appcache/application_1533622723243_17238/container_e38_1533622723243_17238_01_000004/./reducer_wordcount.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
            at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
            ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
            ... 16 more
```

Comment: In reducer_wordcount.sh it's `/usr/bin/env` not `/user/bin/env`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Making files available for tasks](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.6/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Making_Files_Available_to_Tasks) and [Packaging files for job submission](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.6/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Packaging_Files_With_Job_Submissions)

Basically, you only require the file name for the scripts, not a path

```
-reducer 'reducer_wordcount.sh' -file /local/path/to/reducer_wordcount.sh
```

Make sure the file is executable

```
 chmod +x /local/path/to/reducer_wordcount.sh
```

You can optionally rename the file using the `#` marker as shown in the links, but your local script name is the same as the reducer file, so that's not necessary.

You also need to fix the shebang to this `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

(by the way, your mapper and reducer are doing the same thing, counting lines, not necessarily "words")

Comment: But  I have mentioned full path for -file only                                                              
` -file /home/pathirippilly/map_reduce_jobs/shell_scripts/reducer_wordcount.sh ` . This is because I am submitting the job from _/home/pathirippilly/_ but my reducer job is in above first mentioned path. And this reducer is not available in clusters , so only using -file to ship the reducer to the cluster.

Comment: As you said , even if I execute as : ` hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming- 2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292.jar -input /user/pathirippilly/cards/smalldeck.txt  -output /user/pathirippilly/mapreduce_jobs/output_shell -mapper 'wc -l' -reducer 'reducer_wordcount.sh'
 still I am getting the same error : 
` No such file or directory ` 
I am still confused where I am going wrong –

Comment: From what you just pasted, you're not giving a `-file` flag, which is still required if you refer to the two links. You additionally need to set the executable bit on your script

Comment: I didn't get it :(. Can you show me just one small example or a full format of the argument, I am pretty new to this

Comment: The example is in the links... One of them shows python script, but that doesn't really matter here. Are you even able to run the examples shown in the documentation?

Comment: Even I have tried with python reducer and mapper file as in the link , this time error for both reducer and mapper,says no such file or directory:                                                          
  `hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292.jar 
  -files /home/pathirippilly/map_reduce_jobs/python_jobs/mapper.py,/home/pathirippilly/map_reduce_jobs/python_jobs/reducer.py 
  -mapper mapper.py 
  -reducer reducer.py 
  -input  /user/pathirippilly/sample_data_mr/sample.txt 
  -output /user/pathirippilly/mapreduce_jobs/output_python`

Comment: I am getting error on below paths, I guess these are data nodes:
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hdp01/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/pathirippilly/appcache/application_1533622723243_18064/
container_e38_1533622723243_18064_01_000007/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory`
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hdp01/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/pathirippilly/appcache/application_1533622723243_18064/
container_e38_1533622723243_18064_01_000005/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't know the source of the error, unfortunately, but I have ran Hadoop Streaming before as you are doing, and I am sure it works as expected. If you go to the YARN UI, it lists the files sent to the container see if the scripts are listed there. The `mapper` and `reducer` scripts must be local files, not HDFS paths.

Comment: mapper and reducer are in local path only.what ever file I am packing and sending to the DNs are not getting executed and throwing the same error. I am using a Big data lab on HDP with 7 Data nodes.I am not sure if any property values of conf files are causing this problem, spark jobs , sqoop jobs , normal MR jobs in Java are working perfectly here. Thought of just try Hadoop streaming , but ended up on this error.Let me do some research from my side . Thanks for responding quickly and repeatedly for every question of mine ane Thanks for ur suggestions

Comment: I can try running the HDP sandbox to reproduce the problem, but I've not used that thing in maybe 3 years

Comment: it will be great and helpful if you get some time to check from your end on your free time